# Add an object to a deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an object that looks like this:

```
const state = {
  meta: {
    attrs: [ 'dude' ],
    data: {
      foo: 'bar',
      stuff: [
        'x',
        'y',
      ]
    },
  },
}
```

And I want to add an object as a child to the `data` property, creating this:

```
const state = {
  meta: {
    attrs: [ 'dude' ],
    data: {
      foo: 'bar',
      stuff: [
        'x',
        'y',
      ],
      hello: 'world',
    },        
  },
}
```

Note, the addition of `hello: 'world'` as a child in the `data` object:

[image: hello world as child]

Using `Object.assign` I know that I can accomplish my task this way:

```
const hello = {
  hello: 'world',
}
const data = Object.assign(
  {},
  state.meta.data,
  hello,
)
const meta = Object.assign(
  {},
  state.meta,
  {
    data,
  },
)
const updatedState = Object.assign(
  {},
  state,
  {
    meta,
  },
)
```

Is it possible to accomplish this task using fewer `Object.assign` calls?

Comment: `state.meta.data.hello = 'world'`?

Comment: i want to try and not mutate the object, but instead return a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the spread operator syntax as well as

```js
const state = {
  meta: {
    attrs: [ 'dude' ],
    data: {
      foo: 'bar',
      stuff: [
        'x',
        'y',
      ]
    },
  },
}

var data = {
    ...state, meta: {
        ...state.meta, data: {
            ...state.meta.data, hello: 'world'
        }
      }
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.assign(state.meta.data,{hello:"world"});

console.log(state);
```

Youre cloning each object of the tree which is unnecessary or could be done using JSON:

```
var cloned=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
Object.assign(cloned,{hello:"world"});
```

Comment: @andrew li i wasnt shure what the OP wanted. the under one does what he expects